# ASP.NET DataGrid Header Width

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, web, datagrid

ASP.NET DataGrid, after I bind data to the GridView, how can I adjust the column header width so it's not wrapped.

here is the code behind

```
using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection(_sqlServer))
        {
            using (SqlCommand _cmd = _conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                _cmd.CommandText = 
                    "select * from Clients order by ID desc";
                using (SqlDataAdapter _da = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd))
                {
                    DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
                    _da.Fill(_ds);
                    gvClients.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];
                    gvClients.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvClients" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Client" HeaderText="Client" SortExpression="Client" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientID" HeaderText="Client ID" SortExpression="ClientID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactInfo" HeaderText="Contact Info" SortExpression="ContactInfo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AssignedTech" HeaderText="Assigned Tech" SortExpression="AssignedTech" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I have tried

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ContactInfo" HeaderText="Contact Info" ItemStyle-Width = "300px" SortExpression="ContactInfo" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ContactInfo" HeaderText="Contact Info" HeaderStyle-Width="300px" SortExpression="ContactInfo" />
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS that may be overriding or conflicting with these width values? Specifically, any CSS related to `th` or `td`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also try this

```
private void grv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        e.Row.Cells[3].Width = Unit.Pixel(300);
}
```

you can also try CSS solution for not wrapping header row of

```
th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are Adjust your header column in Row data bound Event of Grid View 
Using following Code

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
     e.Row.Cells[ColumnIndex].Width = Unit.Pixel(Width in Number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false"></asp:GridView>
```